# How to scrape mutiple tags of single container in Scrapy using Xpath?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I used Xpath to **scrape** data in a website:

```
response.xpath('//*[@class="attr category hide--mobile"]/span/a/text()').extract()
```

it gives the following result which are tags to a post in a website.

```
['Furniture',
 'Wardrobes',
 'Furniture',
 'Wardrobes',
 'Furniture',
 'Wardrobes',
 'Furniture',
 'Wardrobes',
 'Furniture',
 'Wardrobes',
 'Furniture',]
```

Problem is the first two values are the tags of the same container on the website.

The website contains data like this in a single container:

```
White and Grey Galley Walk-in Closet PLYJ17017-057
White and Grey Galley Walk-in Closet PLYJ17017-057 Specification: Code: PLYJ17017-057 Style: Modern Door: Lacquer Carcase: Melamine White and Grey Galley Walk-in Wardrobe Closet, an important part of the design for the bedroom is the addition of a...
Category: Furniture | Wardrobes
```

How to capture two tags Furniture and Wardrobes as a whole of the single container.

Comment: Can you give a website URL or HTML code fragment?

Comment: the single container i showed above is the HTML fragment

Comment: It's not your target HTML (there is no `a` tags inside)

Comment: Hello sir, thank you for your concern, I have updated my query here. can you please help me on that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51825336/how-to-scrap-paginated-links-in-scrapy