# How to scrape paginated links in Scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

The code for my scraper is :

```
import scrapy


class DummymartSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'dummymart'
    allowed_domains = ['www.dummymart.com/product']
    start_urls = ['https://www.dummymart.net/product/auto-parts--118']
    
    
    def parse(self, response):
        Company = response.xpath('//*[@class="word-wrap item-title"]/text()').extract()
        

        for item in zip(Company):
            scraped_info = {
                'Company':item[0],

            }
            yield scraped_info
        next_page_url = response.css('li >a::attr(href)').extract_first()
        #next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
        if next_page_url:
        
            yield scrapy.Request(url = next_page_url, callback = self.parse)
```

The paginated link has following html syntax:

```
<ul class="pagination">
                                                                <li class="active"><a href="#">1 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="https://www.dummy.net/product/auto-parts--118?page=2">2</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="https://www.dummy.net/product/auto-parts--118?page=3">3</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="https://www.dummy.net/product/auto-parts--118?page=4">4</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="https://www.dummy.net/product/auto-parts--118?page=5">5</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="https://www.dummy.net/product/auto-parts--118?page=6">6</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="https://www.dummy.net/product/auto-parts--118?page=7">7</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="https://www.dummy.net/product/auto-parts--118?page=8">8</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="https://www.dummy.net/product/auto-parts--118?page=9">9</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="https://www.dummy.net/product/auto-parts--118?page=10">10</a></li>
                                            <li class="disabled"><span>...</span></li>
                                <li><a href="https://www.dummy.net/product/auto-parts--118?page=2" aria-label="Next"><span aria-hidden="true">»</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
```

The problem is it only scrapes the first paginated link and not others.
How do i scrap through those two paginated links too? Thanks.

The HTML selector when 2nd page is active:

```
<ul class="pagination">
                    <li><a href="https://www.dummy.net/products/new?page=1" aria-label="Prev"><span aria-hidden="true">«</span></a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="https://www.dummy.net/products/new?page=1">1</a></li>
                                                <li class="active"><a href="#">2 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                                                <li><a href="https://www.dummy.net/products/new?page=3">3</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="https://www.dummy.net/products/new?page=4">4</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="https://www.dummy.net/products/new?page=5">5</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="https://www.dummy.net/products/new?page=6">6</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="https://www.dummy.net/products/new?page=7">7</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="https://www.dummy.net/products/new?page=8">8</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="https://www.dummy.net/products/new?page=9">9</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="https://www.dummy.net/products/new?page=10">10</a></li>
                                        <li class="disabled"><span>...</span></li>
                            <li><a href="https://www.dummy.net/products/new?page=3" aria-label="Next"><span aria-hidden="true">»</span></a></li>
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this method (I'm trying to find a link after current page):

```
next_page_url = response.xpath('//li[ ./a[@class="curr"] ]/following-sibling::li[1]/a/@href').extract_first()
#next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
if next_page_url:

    yield scrapy.Request(url = next_page_url, callback = self.parse)
```

**UPDATE**
According to your new HTML you need this code:

```
next_page_url = response.xpath('//li/a[@aria-label="Next"]/@href').extract_first()
if next_page_url:
    yield scrapy.Request(url = next_page_url, callback = self.parse)
```

Comment: sorry, but it is an empty list

Comment: In [4]: response.xpath('//li[ ./a[@class="curr"] ]/following-sibling::li[1]/a/@href').extract()
Out[4]: []

Comment: @jacksmith I'm sure source HTML (you can check it with `Ctrl+U`) doesn't contain your HTML fragment above. You need always check source HTML.

Comment: <ul class="pagination">
                                                 <li class="active"><a href="#">1 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                                                <li><a href="https://www.ecplaza.net/product/auto-parts--118?page=2">2</a></li>
                                    
                                       
                            <li><a href="https://www.ecplaza.net/product/auto-parts--118?page=2" aria-label="Next"><span aria-hidden="true">»</span></a></li>
                </ul>

Comment: i have updated the question. please have a look. thank you

Comment: @jacksmith Please post HTML source fragment from a *second* page

Comment: I have updated the question cause comment section allowed fewer characters. Please have a look.